# When using Vue and Flask how should user sessions be stored?

Tags: vue.js, flask, web-applications, flask-login

I'm currently working on an app where users are able to log in and access their data from Firebase. The app used to just be a Flask app, so I used `flask_login` to help keep track of user sessions.

However, I'm now trying to use Vue for the front end (including the routing), so technically we will be running a Vue app as well as a Flask app where the Vue app will be making GET requests to the Flask app. I found a [tutorial](https://blog.sqreen.io/authentication-best-practices-vue/) for authentication in Vue. I was wondering if I needed to both this as well as `flask_login`. If so, how would that look like?

Comment: It looks like part of your question got cut off.

Comment: I would suggest you use Flask-Security (It includes Flask-Login and others), then on your API views, use @auth_token_required decorator that requires each call to be authenticated with a token

Comment: @MosesN.Njenga so would the Vue session and the Flask session share the same token?
Jennifer thanks for pointing that out, i updated the question!

Comment: @Kevin the way I would approach it, logging in on the  vue app would mean calling the flask app with a password and user name, and the flask app returning authentication token if login successful. The vue app would then make subsequent requests using the token to a flask view with the auth_token_required decorator

Answer (score 1):

Really late, but since this is not answered, I will give it a go:

I would recommend going with JSON web tokens (JWT). [This post](https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/#:%7E:text=This%20is%20why%20JWTs%20have,to%20be%20valid%20fairly%20quickly.) probably explains it better than I ever will.

The basic flow would be:

On the [flask] backend every API call that needs protection will have a decorator (similar to @login_required) that protects the resource from being accessed by users not authenticated. For a user to be authenticated they will need to fetch from "/login" and the server will respond with a token, store this in memory. This token will need to be sent with any subsequent API call. When the user logs out, simply nullify the token on the front end.

On my setup, I used flask-jwt-extended and on vue, simply make sure that you have a token stored, if not, render a login modal or popup or redirect to the login page.

Read the post I mentioned to understand the JWT refresh flow.